# .NET Native и RyuJIT

Tags: c#, c++, .net, .net-native

Недавно, прочитав интервью от Джеффри Рихтера, узнал о **.NET Native** компиляторе, который превращает код CIL в нативный код, неотличимый от кода после компиляции С++, также узнал о **RyuJIT** и появилось несколько вопросов, ответы на которые я не нашел в интернете:

1. **.NET Native** и **RyuJIT** - это одно и то-же? В какой код компилирует **RyuJIT**?
2. XAMARIN тоже компилирует в натив, не эти ли компиляторы они используют?
3. В боксе VisualStudio 2013 уже есть поддержка этих компиляторов? Если есть - как использовать и как оно действует?, если нет - КАКОГО ЧЕРТА НЕ ВВЕЛИ??

Comment: Схлопотали бан в гугле?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative
>> The .NET Native Developer Preview 2 installs on  Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: Видел, в том и дело. Что обозначает это обновление? Как заставить VS проект WPF (например) скомпилировать натив?

Comment: @BjornMelgaard: это означает

* обновите Visual Studio 2013 до Update 2
* установите .NET Native Developer Preview 2
* профит.

Comment: Большое спасибо, @VladD, я понял, что неправильно интерпретировал комментарий @Flammable: почему-то я решил, что .NET Native уже стоит в Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, видимо сказывается языковой барьер.

Подскажите, вообще стоит пользоваться .NET Native-компилятором для увеличения скорости и уменьшения ресурсопотребления? Или по старинке может писать критичные участки на С++?

Comment: @BjornMelgaard: Я бы сказал, что надо

* для начала, написать всё на C#
* отпрофилировать! обязательно! профилирование в 90% случаев показывает, что критический по времени участок вовсе не тот, который нам подозрителен
* провести оптимизацию найденного участка.
* повторить профилирование, убедится, что оптимизация сработала
* ну вы знаете

Я бы не ставил всё покамест на .NET Native, т. к. технология новая и необкатанная, и наверняка нету хороших инструментов поддержки (например, профайлер может не работать, Castle Windsor/сериализация/...). Но обязательно попробовал бы.

Comment: Очень интересно, я понял, секрет скорости программы в пряморукости пишущего и ...все-таки нужно знать как совмещать в одном проекте решения на разных языках. Что же,учиться есть где.

Сама причина того, что я задаю эти вопросы в том, что мой сосед унижает С#, ссылаясь на то, что С++ "быстрее". Я конечно знаю, что это два разных инструмента, но мое сердце уже принадлежит шарпу за его красоту и понятность, и меня огорчает тот факт, что С++ обеспечивает более тесную связь с машиной(поправьте меня, но все, что я видел, подтверждает это). Представьте мою радость, когда я открыл для себя .NET Nativ

Comment: оказывается можно написать часть кода на С# и она ни в чем не будет уступать С++.
Представьте, не нужно будет писать критическую часть на С++, а может таким способом можно будет на C# и операционные системы писать?

Comment: @BjornMelgaard: C++ быстрее? [Ха-ха-ха](/questions/189730/). Пусть попрофилирует сначала.

А операционные системы вполне себе можно писать на C#. [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29), [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpOS_%28operating_system%29).

---
Совмещать код на C++ и C# очень легко. Нужна лишь тонкая прослойка на C++/CLI, в ней можно писать полностью нативный код, и экспортировать .NET-классы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

о RuyJIT, о том, как его попробовать, можно почитать на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196596/). Если очень коротко,  то это сильно переписаный код стандартного JIT компилятора из .NET.

> .NET Native и RyuJIT - это одно и то-же? В какой код компилирует RyuJIT?

и нет, и да. .NET Native пытается сделать код для конкретной платформы. RyuJIT - это просто улучшенный компилятор .NET. Умеет ли он делать native код - непонятно.

> XAMARIN тоже компилирует в натив, не эти ли компиляторы они используют?

XAMARIN базируется на проекте Mono (это свободная версия .NET, которая работает на многих платформах, в том числе и на линуксе, достаточно совместима с .NET).  Поэтому, короткий  ответ на эти два вопроса - нет и (скорее всего) нет.

> В боксе VisualStudio 2013 уже есть поддержка этих компиляторов? Если есть - как использовать и как оно действует?, если нет - КАКОГО ЧЕРТА НЕ ВВЕЛИ??

в статье на хабре есть описание как ее потестить. Не ввели, потому что похоже только разрабатывается. А .NET Native получается, если использовать nugen (утилита из поставки .Net framework).

Answer (score 4):

1) Нет. RyuJIT — это улучшенная версия JIT-компилятора, а .NET Native вовсе не JIT. [JIT == just in time, программа компилируется в нативный код во время выполнения. .NET Native компилирует в нативный код на машине разработчика.]

2) Не знаю, не имел дела с Xamarin. Не думаю, что там нативная компиляция, скорее всего, он основан на Mono.

3) Да. Смотрите комментарий [[@Flammable](/users/10467/flammable)](/users/10467/flammable).